# Ошибка при подсчете записей в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Попытался реализовать систему комментариев. Хотелось сделать так, чтобы выводилось число комментариев. Сделал теоретически правильный запрос, но он выдает ошибку.
Запросы местами менял, не помогло. Возможно, не так.

```
    $post_comments = mysql_query($db,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE post_id='$post_id'");
 $post_comments2 = mysql_fetch_array($post_comments);
```

Запрос не выдает количество записей, удовлетворяющих условию, а выдает ошибку:

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in
```

P.S. Для данного условия нет записей. Таблица пуста, но 0 должен выдаваться, он опять же не выдается. Подскажите, в чем ошибка или как правильно составить запрос? Заранее спасибо!

Попробовал сделать код вот таким, ошибки обращения пропали, но выдает array в ответ, вместо числового значения:

```
$post_comments  = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE post_id='$post_id'");
 $post_comments2 = mysqli_fetch_row($post_comments);
```

Comment: расширение MySQL официально устарело, и скоро будет выпелено из PHP. Используйте MySQLi или PDO.
Ну это так, совет на будущее

Answer (score 1):

Функции [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) первым параметром передается sql запрос, вторым - идентификатор соединения. А у вас наоборот

Также используйте ключевое слово AS, если что-то считаете. Так удобнее.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_comments FROM comments
```

Comment: @mountpoint Подскажите, а как будет правильно все выглядеть. Я попробовал сделать, как вы говорили, но ошибка опять же не пропадает. Это может быть как то связанно с тем, что в базе нет записей ?